# Loaded event of a WPF user control fires more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

To implement a tab-based environment in **WPF** we need to convert our forms to user controls, however when doing this, the `Loaded` event of the user control is called *two times*.

While searching on the internet other people also pointed this issue. How can we ensure that loaded event is called only once? Because when it is called multiple times, initialization of our controls happens multiple times.

Comment: I tried reproducing this in an empty .NET 4.0 WPF application and the Loaded event only fired once. Have you tried looking at the call stack to see if maybe something weird is going on in the .NET Framework before it fires the Loaded event?

Comment: Place your user control inside a tab control, and you'll be able to reproduce the issue when switching tabs.

Comment: Try using Pages and Frames. It's much simpler and cleaner for grouping controls.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As explained in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx), the Loaded event is fired when ever a control is about to be rendered (i.e. added to the visual tree).

There are several controls that would cause your control to be loaded/unloaded multiple times. For example, the native WPF TabControl only renders the content of the selected tab. So when you select a new tab, the content of the previously selected tab is unloaded. If you click back to the previously selected tab, then it's content is reloaded.

One work around is to use a Boolean to flag whether you have already initialized your control, as suggested by others. Alternatively, you may be able to use the [Initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized) event instead.

Comment: I'm using TabControl's `ItemsSource` to bind several tabs and use `DataTemplate` to bind ViewModel to the tab views. In my case, not only is the `Loaded` event fired again but also the **constructor** of the tab view is called again. It seems that WPF is re-creating my tab control completely each time I switch the tab.

Comment: @Felix I'm facing the same issue, any solution?

Comment: @Luke This is an issue that we can't change. So I save everything in the ViewModel and let WPF recreate it every time.

Answer (score 27):

Your routed event handler can (and should) remove itself from the `Loaded` hook as the first thing it does.

```
public class MyClass : Window
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Loaded += MyLoadedRoutedEventHandler;
    }

    void MyLoadedRoutedEventHandler(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= MyLoadedRoutedEventHandler;
        /// ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Well.. your suggestion has certainly saved my sorry ass, Glenn... but can you explain why this removal should take place INSIDE the event handler? Thanks

Comment: @RichardHammond Because, at what earlier opportunity can you positively be assured that the event has indeed successfully fired? Where else would you suggest to put the removal?

Answer (score 3):

Set a `loaded` flag in the event, and, if the flag has already been set, don't do anything.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, is this really a genuine issue and loaded event called two times due to tab

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above,you can use bool flag for it.

```html
bool isPageLoadingForFirstTime = true;

public void LoadedEvent()
{
  if(ispageLoadingForFirstTime)
   {
      //do something
      ispageLoadingForFirstTime = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).