# Two Loaded events with no intervening Unloaded in in second tab, is it a bug?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my MainWindow code, which contains a `TabControl`:

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlNS.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControlNS"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Visibility="Visible">
            <TabItem Header="Item2">
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Item1">
                <ContentControl Loaded="ContentControl_Loaded">
                    <local:View/>
                </ContentControl>        
            </TabItem>              
            <TabItem Header="Item3"/>
            <TabItem Header="Item4"/>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="TabControlNS.View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControlNS"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here's the code behind:

```
public partial class View : UserControl
{
    public System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host;
    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged += View_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged;

        host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
        var mtbDate = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox("00/00/0000");
        grid.Children.Add(host);
        this.Loaded += View_Loaded;
        this.Unloaded += View_Unloaded;
    }

    private double LoadMinusUnloadCount = 0;

    private void View_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadMinusUnloadCount++;   
    }

    private void View_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadMinusUnloadCount--;
    }

    private void View_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"View.IsKeyboardFocusedWithin = {IsKeyboardFocusWithin}");
    }
}
```

Since the `local:View` control is embedded inside "Item1", then `View_Loaded` will be called twice ( once when the Window is starting up, another when the "Item1" is coming to view). ***No Unloaded event has been called in between.***

[According to Same Bent of Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee9672ed-a991-4dc1-9c92-a015ca2d99d3/when-exactly-are-the-loaded-unloaded-events-raised?forum=wpf&prof=required), this is clearly a bug

> I encourage you to report bugs about things that are clearly wrong,
>   such as
>
> - Unloaded events with no matching Loaded
> - **Two Loaded events with no intervening Unloaded**
> - Element clearly visible and active but no Loaded

Or is it? Can Microsoft make such an elementary bug with such a control? How to explain this?

Comment: worth looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421303/loaded-event-of-a-wpf-user-control-fire-two-times

Comment: When a TabItem is added explicitly, it's indeed loaded immediately. This shouldn't happen if you use the ItemsSource property though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a bug, but there are really several controls in WPF behaviors like this.

The controls that will raise `Loaded` twice without `Unloaded` are:

- `TabControl`
- `Popup`

When the controls are added to the visual tree, the `Loaded` event will be raised to all of its children. And when the child shows or opens, the `Loaded` event will raise again. When the child closes, the `Unloaded` event will raise once. And when the `TabControl` or `Popup` was removed from the visual tree, the `Unloaded` event will be raised again.

---

When a tab control is added to a visual tree:

- `TabControl Loaded` -> `TabItem0 Loaded` -> `TabItem1 Loaded` -> …

When the tab control changed tab:

- `Old Active Tab Unloaded` -> `New Active Tab Loaded`

This means that all `TabItem`s will be `Loaded` twice and `Unloaded` twice.

The `Popup` has a similar behavior.

When a popup is added to a visual tree:

- `Popup Loaded` -> `Child Loaded`

When the popup is opened:

- `Child Loaded`

When the popup is closed:

- `Child Unloaded`

When the popup is Removed from a visual tree:

- `Popup Unloaded`

But if the popup is opened and is removed from a visual tree:

- `Popup Unload` -> `Child Unloaded` (This may be not very expected.)

---

Actually, I believe that WPF has many bugs. My friends and I post them on GitHub:

- [The undefined behaviors of WPF Grid (the so-called bugs) - walterlv](https://walterlv.github.io/post/the-bugs-of-grid-en.html)
- [dotnet-campus/wpf-issues: This repository provides small demo programs and code snippets to reproduce several wpf-related bugs.](https://github.com/dotnet-campus/wpf-issues)
- [dotnet-campus/TouchIssueOnWindows10.0.17134: On Windows 10 (1803), all applications lost touch or stylus if a WPF transparent window covers on them](https://github.com/dotnet-campus/TouchIssueOnWindows10.0.17134)